# Wamp with specific port and SSL

Tags: php, apache, ssl, wamp

I managed to install ssl on wamp, and it seems to run nicely. However, by default I used url-rewritten apps where I had to set the main server url to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

The problem is I can only run ssl on port 443, here is my httpd listen:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
```

And virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/"
ServerName 127.0.0.1:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "logs/sslerror_log"
TransferLog "logs/sslaccess_log"
```

I tried adding 8080 here, but no luck
Any idea?

Comment: Silly question but, did you reload after applying changes?

Comment: What is your `VirtualHost` definition? I.e., what's in `<VirtualHost (.*)>`

Comment: Yes, I reloaded the whole wamp service.
VirtualHost:

    <VirtualHost _default_:443>

Comment: You cannot have Apache listening on the same port for two different protocols. You can change 443 to lets say 4433 if you wanted. But cannot use 8080 for plain and sll access at the same time.

Comment: ouch, I see. Is there any way I can have it work so that, like the http version, it displays the port number in the url? Right now, it redirects me to the server address without it